# Caddy, MariaDB, PHP running as Docker containers on a virtual server (AlmaLinux 9)

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mariadb, caddy

I want to set up Cadddy,
MariaDB and PHP 8.2 with FPM
for hosting a Shopware 6 production installation on a virtual server running AlmaLinux 9.I 'm very new to this so any tips are highly appreciated!

I 've root access to the virtual server and set up the following directories

lcmp(
for linux, caddy, mariadb, php)

in /lcmp I have the following directories and files

docker-compose.yaml
/caddy_docker / www

Here is the docker - compose.yaml

```
#PHP Service php: build: './php_docker/'volumes: -. / www / :/var/www / html /

#Caddy Service caddy: build: './caddy_docker/'depends_on: -php ports: -"80:80" - "443:443"volumes: -. / www / :/var/www / html /

#MariaDB Service mariadb: image: mariadb: 10.11 environment: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <root db pw volumes: -mysqldata: /var/lib / mysql

#phpMyAdmin Service phpmyadmin: image: phpmyadmin / phpmyadmin: latest ports: -8080 : 80 environment: PMA_HOST: mariadb depends_on: -mariadb

#Volumes volumes: mysqldata:
```

In / caddy_docker there is the Dockerfile

````
#Update package index and upgrade installed packages RUN apk update && apk upgrade

#Copy Caddyfile to configure Caddy server COPY Caddyfile / etc / caddy / Caddyfile```

and Caddyfile

```domain.tld: 80 {
    reverse_proxy php: 9000 {
        import php_common
    }
}

(php_common) {
    root * /var/www / html file_server php_fastcgi php: 9000 log {
        output stdout
    }
}```

In / php_docker I have(the extensions are required by Shopware 6) from

[https: //github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer][1]

```FROM php: 8.2 - fpm - alpine

#Downloading install - php - extensions script and making it executable ADD https: //github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension- 
installer / releases / latest / download / install - php - extensions / usr / local / bin / install - php - extensions RUN chmod + x / usr / local / bin / install - php - extensions

#Installing PHP extensions using install - php - extensions script RUN install - php - extensions\mysqli\pdo\pdo_mysql\gd\zip\intl\xml\curl\dom\fileinfo\iconv\json\libxml\mbstring\openssl\pcre\phar\simplexml\zlib

#Cleaning APK cache RUN rm - rf /
var / cache / apk
/*
````

In / www there is a simple index.php with

`<?php phpinfo(); ?`

I have a domain < domain.tld that when opened in the browser should show the index.php The domain is connected via DNS a records to the virtual server, there is no issues with that.

Docker was installed on this virtual server with the following steps

```
    1. dnf upate 
    2. dnf install yum - utils 
    3. dnf config - manager--add - repo https: //download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
    4. sudo dnf install docker - ce docker - ce - cli containerd.io
```

then started and enabled with

`systemctl start docker`
`systemctl enable docker`

The docker service is up and running.Running docker compose up -d works here is the output

```
    docker compose up -d
      
    WARN[0000] Found orphan containers ([lcmp-apache-1]) for this project. If you removed 
    or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command
    [+] Running 4/4
    ✔ Container lcmp-mariadb-1     Running
    ✔ Container lcmp-php-1         Running
    ✔ Container lcmp-phpmyadmin-1  Running
    ✔ Container lcmp-caddy-1       Started
```

Here is the output of

```
    docker ps
    CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                 
    CREATED          
    STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
    562fb44c3043   phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   26 minutes ago   
    Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080-80/tcp, :::8080-80/tcp   lcmp-phpmyadmin-1
    8f778648eed9   mariadb:10.11                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 minutes ago   
    Up 26 minutes   3306/tcp                                lcmp-mariadb-1
    59482a5db10a   lcmp-php                       "docker-php-entrypoi…"   26 minutes ago   
    Up 26 minutes   9000/tcp                                lcmp-php-1
```

**What I want:**

1. Open browser
2. Enter domain.tld
3. See output of index.php

**What currently happens**

Running curl localhost from the terminal returns

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Entering domain.tld

domain.tld took too long to respond ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT*/

Answer (score 1):

It works now, not sure about security but the content of whatever I put into the /www folder is displayed in the browser when entering the url specified in the Caddyfile now, sorry for the bad formatting in the original question, it was the only way I could post it. Anyways, here is my updated Caddyfile in /lcmp/caddy_docker

```
domain.tld {
    root * /var/www/html
    php_fastcgi php:9000
    file_server
}
```

I've created two new directories in /lcmp/caddy_docker/

- /caddy_config
- /caddy_data

Here is the updated docker-compose.yaml in /lcmp

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  # PHP Service
  php:
    build: './php_docker/'
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html/

  # Caddy Service
  caddy:
    build: './caddy_docker/'
    depends_on:
      - php
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "443:443/udp"
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html/
      - ./caddy_docker/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config

  # MariaDB Service
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <redacted>
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql

  # phpMyAdmin Service
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```